# Enable and Disable Chef client

Tags: chef-infra

How does one disbale chef-client and the reverse of that, to re-eanble it?

```
         recipe[syseng::site_server] (syseng@tradingtechnologies.com)
```

Platform:    centos 7.6.1810
Data Center: mock-chicago
Tags:        []

Last chef-client run: 2021-01-05 16:11:09 CST

Type "aliases" to see useful aliases.

::::::CHEF-CLIENT DISABLED::::::

Comment: Do you mean you have `chef-client` running as daemon, and you would like to *not run* it sometimes?

Comment: just use `sudo systemctl stop chef-client` for that and it will stop the service